# html email tools for testing

Tags: html

I am new to html emails. I am having issues during cross client testing. What is the best resource to help with cross client testing of html emails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several tools:

Litmus http://litmus.com

MailChimp http://www.mailchimp.com

CampaignMonitor http://www.campaignmonitor.com

PutsMail (free) http://putsmail.com

Answer (score 6):

I've always used http://litmus.com/email-previews for this.

Answer (score 1):

I've used most of them and can tell you that the best method is to test directly to each client. Once you are comfortable with sending you can send tests of your emails to gmail and if the design doesn't break then it's pretty safe on modern email clients.

You can check what is supported on which client here:

http://www.email-standards.org

Answer (score 0):

Email on Acid is my current favourite; cheaper than Litmus, in active development (they've just released many more tests) and quite a bit of technical help available for each email client.

http://www.emailonacid.com/

What Litmus has that EoA doesn't (updated Feb 2012):

- sharing your results to a public link (but you can email them to an individual)

You *can* now send a mail by email as well as providing a URL or pasting the HTML in manually.

Answer (score 0):

I like http://www.getresponse.com/ ...it currently has 30-day free trial :)

Answer (score 0):

www.emailslicer.com  is exactly what I need for my clients. I do use htmlforemail.com for testing and some personalized emails but most of my clients needs slice since I do 30-60 creatives daily this saves time. OMG finally someone came up with this idea.
Eric thanks for posting this.